# Cannot import modules in jupyter notebook; wrong sys.path

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am having a problem importing modules in my iPython/Jupyter notebook. The problem fundamentally lies in where the sys.path is pointing to.

From the iPython/Jupyter notebook, `sys.executable` returns:

```
'/usr/bin/python'
```

However, from the command line, it returns:

```
'//anaconda/bin/python'
```

I have tried un-installing and re-installing anacondas, but the problem still remains.

I have also tried augmenting $PYTHONPATH in my bash_profile to include //anaconda/bin/python, but this doesn't resolve it.

Is there anyway to change the sys.path in my jupyter notebook permanently, without simply using sys.path.append(...)?

Comment: sys.executable and sys.path are two different things. https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html

Comment: @runawaykid do you wanna accept any of the answers?

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue. After going through many (like way too many) solutions to this issue found elsewhere, I manage to figure out a solution that at least works in my case.

#### Step1: check the correct executable path of the anaconda environment.

Go on command line, activate the conda environment that is problematic, and check the correct executable path for the environment.

`conda activate {envronment name};`
then on python console,
(>>>)`import sys;sys.executable`

For instance on Linux it will be
`/media/{username}/{path-to}/anaconda3/envs/{environment name}/bin/python`

#### Step2: correct the executable path for jupyter sessions.

From command line, check the path where `kernel.json` of your problematic conda environment is located.

`jupyter kernelspec list`

For instance on Linux it will be: `/home/{username}/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/{environment name}`

Open the `kernel.json` located in that folder and replace the incorrect executable path, as shown below.

```
{
 "argv": [
  "REPLACE-THIS-WITH-THE-CORRECT-EXECUTABLE-PATH",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "environment name",
 "language": "python"
}
```

Hope this works in your case too.

Comment: Thanks for a very clear answer. I am running with anaconda-navigator. Any idea how to change the kernel picked up by jupyter when invoked by anaconda-navigator? I found the kernel used through ```import sys 
print(sys.executable)```

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with anaconda-navigator (heard it for the first time here). May be it would be good idea to ask this as a separate question. I am pretty sure somebody must have encountered the same issue.

Comment: Thank you again. I had to install kernel within the required environment using ```python3 -m ipykernel install --user```. And installed required libraries within this environment (pillow, in my case). This worked.

Comment: This is correct answer. Just make sure ipykernel is installed in the virtualenv.

Comment: On windows I get only one value `jupyter kernelspec list`. Should't this `kernel.json` be different for each environment.

Answer (score 9):

1. Open a new terminal window and see if this helps. If not, proceed with 2.
2. Start a standard Python session from the terminal and type this:

   ```
   >>> import sys
   >>> sys.executable
   ```
3. Do the same in the notebook:

   ```
   In [1]: import sys
           sys.executable
   ```
4. Compare the results. Hopefully, this gives you a clue what is going on.

Comment: From the terminal, I get: '/Users/---/anaconda/bin/python'
From the notebook, I get: '/usr/bin/python'

Could you give me some advice on what this means, and what I should do now?

Comment: Try `/Users/---/anaconda/bin/python/jupyter notebook`.

Comment: That starts the jupyter notebook in the same root environment, but results in a similar divergent sys.path.

Comment: Sorry, please use: `/Users/---/anaconda/bin/jupyter notebook`

Comment: One more try: `hash -r`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98588/discussion-between-runawaykid-and-mike-muller).

Comment: I have this problem but the 2 paths diverge. I can't figure out why? one is pointing to a different python venv for some reason?

Answer (score 4):

My system is Mac. I came across the same problem.

I use my anaconda python installed the packages but my jupyter notebook is not using it and cannot import the modules. I solved the problem by following steps:

#### Step1: check the actual python path you used to install the packages

I run `which python` and it shows the default python I use to install packages:

```
➜  ~ which python
/Users/my_name/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
```

#### Step2: change the jupyter kernel's python path to the above path

I run `jupyter kernelspec list`, it shows 2 kernels my jupyter notebook can use:

```py
Available kernels:
  python3    /Users/my_name/Library/Jupyter/kernels/python3
  python2    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python2
```

Since I usually use python3 in my jupyter, then I choose to edit the first kernel's configuration, run:
`vi /Users/my_name/Library/Jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json`

replace the first path as `"/Users/my_name/opt/anaconda3/bin/python"`(as the `which python` command shows.)

```
{
 "argv": [
  "/Users/my_name/opt/anaconda3/bin/python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "heterodimers",
 "language": "python"
}
```

save and quit the `kernel.json` file.

After that, my jupyter notebook can import the packages I installed in the terminal.

And thanks to Mike's answers because I basically followed his solution to find mine. The difference is that I did not use the conda environment.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above answers solved my issue. In my windows system I tried this and it worked.

```
conda create --name {envname}
conda install ipykernel --name {envname}
python -m ipykernel install --prefix=C:/anaconda/envs/{envname} --name {envname}
activate envname
pip install jupyter
```

Check sys.executable in notebook afterwords to ensure that your prefix is mentioned in the output.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this problem. did a

```sh
find ~ -name kernal.json
```

and got

```
/home/mee/dev/my-venv1/__venv__/share/jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json
/home/mee/dev/my-venv2/__venv__/share/jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json
/home/mee/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json
```

I looked inside `~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json` and found it was pointing to `/home/alex/dev/my-venv2/__venv__/bin/python3`.

I deleted `~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json` and now the one in `my-venv2` is pointing to the correct one and all works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

win11，miniconda3，virtualenv name “sitk”

just run：

```
conda activate sitk
conda install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name sitk
```

solves the problem for SimpleITK import error in jupyter lab