# How to make Jupyter notebook use PYTHONPATH in system variables without hacking sys.path directly?

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook

Same problem as in this question [sys.path different in Jupyter and Python - how to import own modules in Jupyter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34976803/1568919). In pure Python, it prepends my system environment variable PYTHONPATH to sys.path but Jupyter notebook doesn't, so I can't import my own module.

There are many similar questions asked on SO, and the solution is to directly manipulate sys.path in the script.

Is there a way to make Jupyter notebook use my system PYTHONPATH variable, as in pure python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sys.path different in Jupyter and Python - how to import own modules in Jupyter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34976803/sys-path-different-in-jupyter-and-python-how-to-import-own-modules-in-jupyter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jupyter uses its own [JUPYTER_PATH](http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projects/jupyter-directories.html) environment variable.

Comment: The docs doesn't give an example of how to add to it in the config file. I can't get it to work. Could you give an example of how to add it in jupyter_notebook_config.json, by default looking like:

    {
      "NotebookApp": {
        "nbserver_extensions": {
          "ipyparallel.nbextension": true
        }
      }

Comment: Not sure how to do it from config file. The one I had is to make a new system environment variable at where PYTHON_PATH is.

Comment: URL is broken now.

Answer (score 11):

Use simply the `PYTHONPATH`.

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Users/user/my-other-library/
jupyter notebook
```

I just tested with the newest jupyterlab-2.1.2 and it works.

Comment: OP is clearly asking how to do it **inside** the notebook.

Answer (score 3):

JupyterLab reuses the PYTHONPATH on Linux, so I created a file like

```
#!/bin/bash
# add your path
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/opt/your/path"
# start JupyterLab using an environment
/opt/anaconda/envs/MY_ENVIRONMENT/bin/jupyter-lab
```

saved it as `start_my_jupyterlab`, make it executeable with `chmod a+x start_my_jupyterlab` and run it on the shell with `start_my_jupyterlab`.

Comment: This worked well for me. Though for my case (on OSX) the conda environments are under `/Users/ME/anaconda3/envs/MY_ENVIRONMENT/bin/jupyter-lab`

Answer (score 2):

--Just chiming in here since the accepted answer didn't give the complete solution--

You can add the path to your modules to the `JUPYTER_PATH` environment variable, just the same as you would for modifying the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable:

```
export JUPYTER_PATH="${JUPYTER_PATH}:/path/to/add/here/"
```

If you're on a Mac or other Unix system, you would just drop the above line into your `~/.bash_profile`

Hint: make sure you run `source ~/.bash_profile` to enact the changes and close and restart your jupyter notebook.