# How can I pass the PYTHONPATH in Jupyter Lab/Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pythonpath

Ok, this must be silly but I really can't find a good way to do it.

When I open a Python session with Jupyter Notebook or a Jupyter Lab, I cannot have access to all my scripts on other folders which are generally included in PYTHONPATH.

If I run the Jupyter Notebook from Pycharm, it actually works and I can see that I have the correct PYTHONPATH by doing

`import os
os.getcwd()`

but if I do the same with a session started from CLI, I get a `KeyError` and PYTHONPATH not found.

This must have been solved a thousand times, how come I can't find anything about it?

Comment: not at all. I have problems with the PYTHONPATH in the Jupyter notebook. Not with pycharm.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34976803/sys-path-different-in-jupyter-and-python-how-to-import-own-modules-in-jupyter

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43985787/how-to-make-jupyter-notebook-use-pythonpath-in-system-variables-without-hacking