# How to import a module to a script in a sub-directory

Tags: python, directory, python-module

I have a basic directory strucrure

```
model_folder
|
|
------- model_modules
|            |
|             ---- __init__.py
|            |
|             ---- foo.py
|            |
|             ---- bar.py
|
|
------- research
|            |
|            ----- training.ipynb
|            |
|            ----- eda.ipynb
|
|
------- main.py
```

Where `model_modules` is a folder containing two functions that I use in my model, `research` is a folder where I put modeling research, etc., and `main.py` is my main script that tests new data.

My question regards how to import a module, ie `model_modules`, into a script in a sub-directory. I can import `model_modules` into `main.py` just fine by doing the following

```
from model_modules.foo import Foo
from model_modules.bar import Bar
```

But when I try the same thing in `training.ipynb` or `eda.ipynb`, I get the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model_modules'
```

I want my directory to be "clean" and don't want all my research scripts in the root directory. Is there a fix for this so that I can import `model_modules` into scripts in `research`? Or do I need to approach the architecture of this directory differently?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your ipynb is not in the same directory as your module.

In this case, you must add the module path as the code below.

Prepare the absolute path of the model_folder.

I suggest this code below.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/absolute/path/model_folder')
from model_modules.foo import Foo
from model_modules.bar import Bar
```

Let's say, your module path which has submodule directories and python files is '/Users/username/custom_module'

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Users/username/custom_module')
from model_modules.foo import Foo
from model_modules.bar import Bar
```

OR you can use the way below. but If you don't want to dive into the Bash and Linux system world, try the first method I suggested.

```
export PYTHONPATH='/Users/username/custom_module'
```

[more detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58522752/20307768)

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the reply. I wonder, is this "pythonic" or a best practice? Or generally considered not a good idea to use sys  to prepare an absolute path to import modules? Will be upvoting this, as it does indeed solve my problem.

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with Linux or a command line, the first method is most convenient for you. There are similar questions like yours ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49264194/import-py-file-in-another-directory-in-jupyter-notebook )