Set import path for python with jupyter notebooks / vscode
I connect to my own jupyter server via vpn/ssh with vscode.
Jupyter server runs as a daemon.
Having asked gpt, read articles here and tried many config versions, I still end up doing this at the beginning of each notebook:
BASE_PATH = '/home/bartsimpson/dev/'

import sys

sys.path.append(BASE_PATH)

Is there a way to set it somewhere in my jupyter server or in vscode so that I could easily do this without setting path manually?
from library.myclass import MyClass

if it resides in /home/bartsimpson/dev/library/myclass.py ?
P.S. Setting neither PYTHONPATH, nor JUPYTER_PATH prior to launch helps.

Does updating the PYTHONPATH before launching the Jupyter server help at all? Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43985787/how-to-make-jupyter-notebook-use-pythonpath-in-system-variables-without-hacking

It's all about the structure of your file.

Setting neither PYTHONPATH, nor JUPYTER_PATH prior to launch helps. @Daniel

You could go to the directory of the kernel you're using which involves the kernel.json file.
In the same directory, create a new file called ipython_kernel_config.py.
c = get_config()
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = [
    "import sys",
    "sys.path.append('/home/bartsimpson/dev/')",
]

Now, each time you start a Jupyter notebook using this kernel, the lines in exec_lines will be executed

Awesome! Thanks.
Also, for those with similar problem, config folder you can find with command jupyter kernelspec list
