# jupyter notebook lost imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

After installing two additional kernels to Jupyter Notebook (python2 and gophernotes) I can't import any packages, which are already installed.

I tried to find the solution, but all described methods did't worked for me. Here is my environment:

[image]

Please help

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Python3 this helped:

```
export JUPYTER_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python:$JUPYTER_PATH
```

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/46180035/9881344