# I tried everything to set up Web Scraping Libraries (installing requests, lxml and bs4) but just can't get it done

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, jupyter-notebook

I tried everything to set up Web Scraping Libraries (installing requests, lxml and bs4) but just can't get it done.

---

My specs -

- Windows 10 Pro
- Python version - Python 3.8.3
- Using Jupyter Notebook - C:\Users\LENOVO\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter.exe
- Jupyter version - jupyter core: 4.6.3

- jupyter-notebook : 6.0.3
- qtconsole        : 4.7.5
- ipython          : 7.16.1
- ipykernel        : 5.3.2
- jupyter client   : 6.1.6
- jupyter lab      : 2.1.5
- nbconvert        : 5.6.1
- ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
- nbformat         : 5.0.7
- traitlets        : 4.3.3

---

- I installed through pip install - It said `requirements already satisfied`
  (Through both Anaconda and Command Prompt)
- I restarted the system. It didn't work with Jupyter.
- I also tried installing the virtual environment package - It was also installed
  Shows the following error - `ModuleNotFoundError`
- I Googled it and found the following details -

  ```
  python -m pip install requests - (Said 'requirements already satisfied')

  conda install -c anaconda requests - (Said 'Collecting package metadata
  ```

  ```
  (current_repodata.json): done
  Solving environment: done)
  ```

What Should I do now?

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python installed on your computer? For example one with anaconda and one from https://www.python.org/? Try installing each package again with `conda install` instad of `pip install`.

Comment: when i typed 'python --version' it gave me 'Python 3.8.3' only . So I guess only one is installed.

Answer (score 0):

- First, run your jupyter notebook and print `sys.path`.
- Check if your libraries are installed in the directories that your modules reside in, which can be retrieved by running `conda list` or `pip show [module name]`.
- If not, prepend the path to the module to sys.path and try the import again.
  [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34976803/sys-path-different-in-jupyter-and-python-how-to-import-own-modules-in-jupyter)

More about the [python import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html).

Answer (score 0):

I did the following as advised -

sys.path

['C:\Users\LENOVO',
'C:\Users\LENOVO\anaconda3\envs\Python 38\python38.zip',
'C:\Users\LENOVO\anaconda3\envs\Python 38\DLLs',
'C:\Users\LENOVO\anaconda3\envs\Python 38\lib',
'C:\Users\LENOVO\anaconda3\envs\Python 38',
'',
'C:\Users\LENOVO\anaconda3\envs\Python 38\lib\site-packages',
'C:\Users\LENOVO\anaconda3\envs\Python 38\lib\site-packages\win32',
'C:\Users\LENOVO\anaconda3\envs\Python 38\lib\site-packages\win32\lib',
'C:\Users\LENOVO\anaconda3\envs\Python 38\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin',
'C:\Users\LENOVO\anaconda3\envs\Python 38\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions',
'C:\Users\LENOVO\.ipython']

pip show [bs4]

Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
'C:\Users\LENOVO\anaconda3\envs\Python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

pip show [requests]

Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
'C:\Users\LENOVO\anaconda3\envs\Python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

conda list
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MeyL.png)
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
EnvironmentLocationNotFound: Not a conda environment: C:\Users\LENOVO\anaconda3\envs\Python

I'm guessing the issue might be lying [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEqmC.png). But I don't know how to resolve it. I'm using the one marked in Blue - Jupyter Notebook (Python38) (1).

Do I need to uninstall or delete anything ?

[Screenshot from Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MeyL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Finally it worked. I did it the following way -

I checked the path I was working on using -

> import os

> os.getcwd()

*For me --> 'C:\Users\LENOVO'*

Then from the command prompt I checked the path where 'site-packages' are installed using

> pip3 install requests

*(for python3)*
*(This gives the path in cmd prompt after installing)*

*For me --> Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (2.24.0)*

I moved the whole folder(site-packages) from installed path (where 'site-packages' are installed) to the destination path (where I want it to be).

There are a few ways to do it. I used -

> import shutil

> shutil.move('source path','destination path')

*For me --> shutil.move('c:\users\lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages','C:\Users\LENOVO')*

After that go to the 'site-packages' folder, open a kernel and you can import requests , import bs4 and start working!