# How to import packages in python using __init__.py

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've spent hours researching this small problem now, but clearly I wasn't able to figure out how to get my packages to work the way I want them to.

Here's an extract from my project structure:

```
package/
    __init__.py
    code.py
notebooks/
    testing.ipynb
```

With `__init__.py` containing:

```
from .code.py import *
```

Shouldn't I be able to import the functions from code.py within `testing.ipynb` as follows?

```
from ..package import *
```

The error message I'm getting is:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sys.path different in Jupyter and Python - how to import own modules in Jupyter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34976803/sys-path-different-in-jupyter-and-python-how-to-import-own-modules-in-jupyter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Shouldn't I be able to import the functions from code.py within
> testing.ipynb?

#### 1. Try changing the current directory:

```
cd ..
```

And then import on the cell below:

```
from package.code import *
```

#### 2. Placing the `package` directory inside the `notebooks` directory.

Using `import package` with the following directory structure example:

```
notebooks/
    package/
        __init__.py
        code.py
    testing.ipynb
```

#### 3. Adding the paths you want Python to look at for importing at runtime:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "..")

from package.code import *
```

#### or

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "../package")

from code import *
```

Python sets a variable with paths on where it looks for modules and packages. The working directory where the initial script was started is one of those paths. The above code adds the `package` directory to the path.

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path) for an in depth look on how Python path works.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I still do not understand why my initial code wasn't working out since my project structure is exactly as you laid out, however it did work using `import sys`