# Jupyter Notebook (in VS Code) does not "see" files within a sibling directory

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, path, sys

### Context

Contents of the project root directory (`project-name`):

```
.
├── data
│   ├── locations
│   │   ├── location_group_a
│   │   ├── location_group_b
│   │   ├── location_group_c
│   │   ├── location_group_d
│   │   └── pickles
│   └── reviews
│       ├── location_group_a
│       ├── location_group_b
│       ├── location_group_c
│       ├── location_group_d
│       └── pickles
├── project_name <- Contents of this subdirectory are shown below.
├── logs
├── secrets
└── tests
```

Contents of the `project_name` subdirectory:

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── common_utils.py
├── dash_app.py
├── data_download.py
├── data_prep.py
├── data_store.py
├── google_api.py
├── nlp.py
└── scratchpad.ipynb
```

Contents of the first cell in `scratchpad.ipynb` notebook:

```py
import data_prep

df = data_prep.get_reviews_dataframe()

print(sys.path)
```

Contents of `sys.path` (print in `scratchpad.ipynb` notebook):

```
['/Users/my-username/Code/project-name/project_name',
'/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python39.zip',
'/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9',
'/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
'',
'/Users/my-username/Code/project-name/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages',
'/Users/my-username/Code/my-project']
```

(Spaces have been replaced with newlines for improved readability.)

I'm using [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org) to manage my Python project, and I'm [running Jupyter via Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks).

### Problem

The function, `data_prep.get_reviews_dataframe()` uses files from `my-project/data`.

Everything works as expected when I import and call that function in a "normal" Python script (`my-project/my_project/nlp.py`). Meaning the files within `my-project/data` are recognized.

However, when I import and call that same function from within a Jupyter notebook (`my-project/my_project/scratchpad.ipynb`), functions called by `data_prep.get_reviews_dataframe()` cannot "see" the files within the directory `my-project/data`, which causes subsequent function calls to fail.

Here is the stack trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/my-username/Code/my-project/my_project/scratchpad.ipynb Cell 2' in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df = data_prep.get_reviews_dataframe()

File ~/Code/my-project/my_project/data_prep.py:8, in get_reviews_dataframe()
      6 def get_reviews_dataframe():
      7     '''Get a tidy data frame with correct data types containing all reviews.'''
----> 8     df = data_store.load_pickle(json_directory="data/reviews",
      9                                 pickle_directory="data/reviews/pickles",
     10                                 pickle_filename="reviews.pkl")
     11     df = split_review_comment(df, "comment")
     12     df = extract_ids_from_field(df, "name")

File ~/Code/my-project/my_project/data_store.py:55, in load_pickle(json_directory, pickle_directory, pickle_filename, update_pickle, overwrite_pickle)
     53 latest_pickle_filename = get_latest_pickle_filename(pickle_directory)
     54 if latest_pickle_filename == None or update_pickle == True:
---> 55     filename = json_to_pickle(
     56         json_path=json_directory,
     57         pickle_path=pickle_directory,
     58         pickle_filename=pickle_filename,
     59         force_update=overwrite_pickle)
     60 else:
     61     filename = f"{pickle_directory}/{latest_pickle_filename}"

File ~/Code/my-project/my_project/data_store.py:107, in json_to_pickle(json_path, pickle_path, pickle_filename, force_update)
    105         with open(path, "r") as file:
    106             data_frames.append(pd.json_normalize(json.load(file)))
--> 107     pd.concat(data_frames).to_pickle(out_path, compression="infer")
    108 else:
    109     pprint(f"Using existing pickle file ({out_path})")

File ~/Code/my-project/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py:311, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    305 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
    306     warnings.warn(
    307         msg.format(arguments=arguments),
    308         FutureWarning,
    309         stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310     )
--> 311 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/Code/my-project/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py:347, in concat(objs, axis, join, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
    143 @deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments(version=None, allowed_args=["objs"])
    144 def concat(
    145     objs: Iterable[NDFrame] | Mapping[Hashable, NDFrame],
   (...)
    154     copy: bool = True,
    155 ) -> DataFrame | Series:
    156     """
    157     Concatenate pandas objects along a particular axis with optional set logic
    158     along the other axes.
   (...)
    345     ValueError: Indexes have overlapping values: ['a']
    346     """
--> 347     op = _Concatenator(
    348         objs,
    349         axis=axis,
    350         ignore_index=ignore_index,
    351         join=join,
    352         keys=keys,
    353         levels=levels,
    354         names=names,
    355         verify_integrity=verify_integrity,
    356         copy=copy,
    357         sort=sort,
    358     )
    360     return op.get_result()

File ~/Code/my-project/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py:404, in _Concatenator.__init__(self, objs, axis, join, keys, levels, names, ignore_index, verify_integrity, copy, sort)
    401     objs = list(objs)
    403 if len(objs) == 0:
--> 404     raise ValueError("No objects to concatenate")
    406 if keys is None:
    407     objs = list(com.not_none(*objs))

ValueError: No objects to concatenate
```

Following the advice in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34976803/sys-path-different-in-jupyter-and-python-how-to-import-own-modules-in-jupyter#comment101447111_42727538), I have tried to add the parent directory to `sys.path`:

```py
sys.path.insert(0, "..")
sys.path.insert(0, "../data")

%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

I have also tried using `sys.path.append` in the same way.

My path is indeed modified after calling those functions, but the same problem persists.

### Question

How can I make Jupyter "see" the files found within `my-project/data`?

`sys.path.append` and `sys.path.insert` don't seem to work.

Comment: Here are three suggestions for you:
You can use the `cd` command to enter the jupyter directory where you need to work.
Did you try adding a snippet to import the path:
`import os
import sys
module_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..'))
if module_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(module_path)`
Also, have you imported the corresponding content in `__init__.py`

Comment: You can try to create a new notebook and do it again.