# Terminal Anaconda not Syncing to Jupyter

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, sklearn-pandas

I've looked everywhere but can't find my situation.
I deleted my previous installation and did a clean install of Anaconda3. 
I think my environment may be out of sync.

In the terminal, I can do 'import sklearn' and its all good. 
In Jupyter, I had to do a '!pip3 install sklearn' then do 'import sklearn'

Alternatively, 
In the terminal, when I do 'pip3 install xgboost' it says 'Requirement already satisfied' 
Then inside the terminal, I'll switch into python and do 'import xgboost' and it gives me a 'ModuleNotFoundError'.  
In Jupyter, I'll do 'import xgboost' and pip needed at all.

FYI - Usually when you do a clean install, anaconda creates a DIR 'AnacondaProjects'.
For this install, I renamed my existing DIR 'AnacondaProjects----' Expecting that Anaconda would re-create this folder again. This did not happen.

Below are some tests that I ran: Any thoughts are appreciated

There is my Jupyter config **`!jupyter --paths`**

`config:
    /Users/namelyme/.jupyter
    /opt/anaconda3/etc/jupyter
    /usr/local/etc/jupyter
    /etc/jupyter
data:
    /Users/namelyme/Library/Jupyter
    /opt/anaconda3/share/jupyter
    /usr/local/share/jupyter
    /usr/share/jupyter
runtime:
    /Users/namelyme/Library/Jupyter/runtime`

**When I run these commands from Terminal and from Jupyter, I get the same answer:**

> `which python` —-/opt/anaconda3/bin/python 
>   `which jupyter` — /opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter

**FROM TERMINAL:**
`sys.executable`

> '/opt/anaconda3/bin/python'

**FROM JUPYTER:**
`sys.executable`

> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3'

When I do `!pip3 install sklearn` I get this error below. 
I've already done 'pip3 install wheel', and that works
I also did done 'pip3 install Cython', and that works too.

Comment: what is your kernel? You can find the kernel on the top-right corner

Comment: Python 3
I dont have any more virtual environments:\n (base) computer-mbp:~ me$ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /opt/anaconda3

Comment: This Post Answered my question: I needed to update kernel.json
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34389029/cannot-import-modules-in-jupyter-notebook-wrong-sys-path